# getIntExtra() and putExtra()?

Tags: android, android-intent

I read Hello Android book and i dont understan the following code.
I dont know, what to do getIntExtra() and putExtra() int this code.

```
 private void startGame(int i) {
     Log.d(TAG, "clicked on " + i);
     Intent intent = new Intent(Sudoku.this, Game.class);
     intent.putExtra(Game.KEY_DIFFICULTY, i);
     startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Game.java

```
public class Game extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Sudoku" ;
    public static final String KEY_DIFFICULTY ="org.example.sudoku.difficulty" ;
    public static final int DIFFICULTY_EASY = 0;
    public static final int DIFFICULTY_MEDIUM = 1;
    public static final int DIFFICULTY_HARD = 2;
    private int puzzle[] = new int[9 * 9];
    private PuzzleView puzzleView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate" );
        int diff = getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_DIFFICULTY,DIFFICULTY_EASY);
        puzzle = getPuzzle(diff);
        calculateUsedTiles();
        puzzleView = new PuzzleView(this);
        setContentView(puzzleView);
        puzzleView.requestFocus();
    }
    // ...
}
```

The problem I have is that you are setting a local integer (‘diff’) within the Game class. with a default value of zero (easy) and then immediately passing it into the getPuzzle method …. how does the user input value ( the real value all being well) ever find it’s way into the getPuzzle method?

Comment: its passed here ---private void startGame(int i)

Comment: Actually, I don't really understand what you want! If you want to get user's input, just create an `EditText` and get everything you want!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Sudoku.this, Game.class); 
 intent.putExtra(Game.KEY_DIFFICULTY, i); 
 startActivity(intent);
```

creates an intent which, when executed with `startActivity`, does two things:

- It starts a new activity of class `Game` (specified by the parameter `Game.class`) and
- it passes `i` (= the user input) into the activity, tagged with the string content of `KEY_DIFFICULTY`.

In the activity, this line:

```
 int diff = getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_DIFFICULTY, DIFFICULTY_EASY);
```

reads the value that was set for `KEY_DIFFICULTY` in the intent used to start the activity. Hence, `diff` now contains the user-selected value (or `DIFFICULTY_EASY`, if the activity is started through a different intent which did *not* set `KEY_DIFFICULTY`).

Comment: Thanks.Actually you mean that in startActivity(i) function, Game class is called and if we have to select one of Difficulty, getIntExtra() not read DIFFICULTY_EASY and instead of to read what we chose . this is true?

Comment: @FahimehHashemian: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Intents are used to start an activity programmatically in android. The intent can carry data, which you pass to the new started activity.

```
startGame(int i)
```

starts the new game activity with an intent. Putting an extra to an intent means, you are passing data over to the intent. The started activity (in your case the Game.java) then can acceess this extra from the intent.

It is a mechanism to pass data between activities.

The first argument (KEY_DIFFICULTY) is the key by which the extra is identified. So if you put an extra to an intent with key 'mykeyexample' you will have to do a get with the same key 'mykeyexample' in another activity to get the desired extra from the intent.

Hope this helps